# What is the PayPal "amount" format in WPS?

Tags: paypal, format, numbers

What is the allowed format for PayPal's Website Payments Standard (WPS) forms in the "amount" field? Must the decimal point be ".", or is it currency-dependant? Must there always be exactly two decimal places, or can there also be three (for currencies that have such small nominations) or none (for currencies that have hyper-inflation)?

I know that this should be a question for PayPal's documentation/forums, but the first has a vast room for improvement (to say the least) and the second is as speedy as a sleeping snail. I have [posted a question](http://www.paypaldeveloper.com/pdn/board/message?board.id=basicpayments&message.id=33343) there, but I don't expect any replies sooner than about two weeks. Hopefully someone here will have an idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like it's not currency dependent and the API is expecting at most two (2) decimal places with a period separator.

> `amount`
>
> [...] Limitations: Value must be a positive number. No currency symbol. Must have two decimal places, decimal separator must be a period (.), and the optional thousands separator must be a comma (,).

[Website Payments Standard Button Manager API Overview](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ButtonMgrAPIIntro)